# How to let build.gradle support multi-language?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a question, I write script "resValue("string", "app_name", "Test")" in the build.gradle file and it occured an error that I have already anounce the same value in the "string.xml" file as "Test".

Here is the question, how to make gradle file support Chinese and English ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why do you want to write chinese in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Why not simply use Android’s built-in localization features, and use XML resources?

Comment: Because this app need to use the Chinese name, and I use versionNameSuffix and applicationId to distinguish the debug or release version, so I want to use app_name to display like this: "app_debug" for debug and "app" for release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an encoding like UTF-8 while building the gradle by setting -

```
-encoding UTF-8 -docencoding utf-8 -charset utf-8
```

Or something like this -

```
android {
 ...
compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
 }
```

Or through the settings -

```
    File -> Settings -> Editor -> File encodings -> set UTF-8 for

    IDE Encoding
    Project Encoding
    Default encoding propertie file

Press OK

Rebuild Project

Build -> Rebuild project
```

Comment: Thank you, but a conflict will happen indicate that the string app_name is redefine.